# SSHFS on Windows 10 not able to change permissions on mapped drive to Ubuntu target

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, permissions, sshfs

I have SSHFS installed in Windows 10 and am having a problem that is driving me crazy trying to figure out what is causing it.

I am using the latest packages (just downloaded and installed 2 days ago) and am mapping drives via use of SSHFS-Win Manager.

I am able to map a drive to an Ubuntu target with no problem and then use Perforce GUI on Windows 10 to check out files. When I check out a file the permissions are NOT changing on the file on Ubuntu server - it continues to be read and execute only. This DOES work when I map that same drive connection using Windows 10 built-in mapped drive. Permissions change fine in that case.

The problem only happens when I map a drive with SSHFS.

I have messed around with the advanced settings in Win manager, including idmap=user, umask variations, default permissions and a few others. No matter what I do the permissions never get changed when I check out a file.

Is there something I'm missing or is this incredibly basic functionality just flat out broken with SSHFS?

I know there have been similar reports of this kind of problem and I have tried all the "solutions" I have found in my searches. NONE of them has helped solve this problem.

Thanks very much
Allen

Comment: Welcome to Super User. 'I have tried all the "solutions" I have found in my searches. NONE of them has helped solve this problem.' What solutions exactly? Please don't waste your and our time by letting us post solutions you have already tried. [Edit] the question and tell us.